# UILabel won't update the first time

Tags: objective-c, text, uilabel

i have a modal view which contains only o button and a uilabel.
The button close the modal v:

```
- (IBAction) close {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now, i create this view:

```
nw = [[NewsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsViewController" bundle:nil];
nw.modalInPopover = YES;
nw.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[nw setValues:@"asdasd"];

[self presentModalViewController:nw animated:YES];
```

all ok.

It loads correctly but the uilabel value don't show me the correct text label.

How it's possible?
Second time click, the value was setted correctly...

This is setValues func:

```
- (void) setValues:(NSString*)val {
    [firstLabel setText:val];
}
```

Debugging, it show first time UILabel 0x0... this is a problem, but second time it's created correctly and the value is setted.

any idea to fix?

alberto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your first call to setValues, `NewsViewController` probably hasn't yet loaded its view. To confirm, set a breakpoint before `[ns setValues:@"asdasd"];` and in the `-[viewDidLoad]` method of `NewsViewController`.

To work around this, you could add an instance variable for the text in `NewsViewController`. Then set the instance variable in `-[setValues:]` and set the label's text in its `-[viewDidLoad]` method from that instance variable.

Comment: yes, i added an instance variable and now it's all ok! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you set label text in `viewDidLoad`, until view had finished loading itself.

Try put in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set text on the main thread

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       firstLabel.text = currentEventsString;
 });
```